# Capture event for fingerprint reader in no active application

Tags: c#, events, fingerprint

I have an application that validates users through a fingerprint reader. The validation is done in a method that i subscribed to manage the event, it looks like this.

FingerprintVerificationControl.OnComplete+=new DPFP.Gui.Verification.VerificationControl._OnComplete(FingerprintVerificationControl_OnComplete);

Everything goes well while i'm woriking with the application, i mean, when it has the focus, but, i have put it in the system tray using a notifyicon control and associating it with a contextmenu control to restore and close the app; so when it is in the system tray (is not the active application) i have no response from the fingerprint to manage the validation; the event of read the finger of the user does not fires.

My question is, what is the best way to manage that? Is it possible?. I found that i can do it if i make a windows service, other sites say that with Win32 API, others have examples but with keyboard events like presss key and so on. Any idea? any idea would be thank.

Answer (score 0):

I have found that making a Windows Service is the best way to do stuff like that. However I don't any about the windows32 API cause I've been able to do everything I can without it.

As for the keyboard events, I have tried those and have found that they only work when the application has focus therefore, they are unusable. And services are just useful in general. You can try to talk to your application from your service via the local network so you don't have to rework the entire application.

I hope this is helpful.

Comment: Ok, do you have a sample refering to manage of the application by the service? How can i detect with a service when the user puts the finger on the device and then notify to the application to execute the stuff i need? Or how do you it? Or should the application be created as a service or how can i do it?

Comment: Hi, 

Were you able to make headways with this? I am also hoping to know programatically when a fingerprint device captures a fingerprint ( fires a fingerprint capture event) but when no application is using the fingerprint device. I am using Digitalpersona like you too.